# getting error doing a search with react and mern

Tags: reactjs, search, react-hooks, axios, mern

I am doing a search with mern, where I type something in the form, and if it exists or equal the same we have in the backend, we display it, if else, we show a phrase not find, like a normal search

first I create a post , then I type in the other form, what I m looking for

but I am getting error when I try to fetch , in react, can someone help me, I appreciate. thanks

I am getting this error
GET http://localhost:3000/post 401 (Unauthorized)

this error  I set in my backend, if I type something that not exist in my db, show not find

and how can I type something that exists, how can I execute this params at react part?

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect} from "react";

function Post() {

    const [post, setPost] = useState([])
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false)
    const [currentPost, setCurrentPost] = useState("")



useEffect (() => {
    const allPost = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get("/post");
        if (setCurrentPost === post ) {
            setPost(res.data);
        } else {
            setPost("not find")
        }

    }
    
    allPost()
}, [])

return (

    <div>

        <form >
            <label></label>

            <input type="search" placeholder="Search"
            onChange={(e)=> setCurrentPost(e.target.value)}/>


        </form>


        <button onClick={()=> setClick(true)}>search</button>
            {click && post.map((post) => (

                <h1>{post.post}</h1>
            ))}


    </div>

    )
}

export default Post;
```

this is my backend

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Post = require ("../models/Post");


router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {  
        const newPost = new Post({
            post: req.body.post
        });

        const post = await newPost.save();
        res.status(200).json(post);

    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});


router.get("/" ,async (req,res ) => {
    const findPost = await Post.findOne({post: req.body.post});
    if(findPost) {
        res.status(200).json(findPost);
    } else {
        res.status(401).json("not find")
    };

})

module.exports = router;
```

and the Schema

```
onst mongoose = require("mongoose")

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    post: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema)
```

Comment: You're going to need to put a lot more information here.  What is the error.  What is the back-end code?  What response is the API supposed to give?  What response is it giving?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I reedited it, I think it is better now

Comment: Are other post calls working normally and is CORS errors on the console ?

Comment: @ChakibSalah no. This error occurs instantly when I load the page, and It doesn't search too. when I click in the error it show for me a post in red style in the network, and the phrase "not find" the same i set up in my backend

Comment: `if (setCurrentPost === post )` <- why would your `currentPost` **setter** ever be equal to your `post` state?

Comment: Why is your `GET /post` route trying to use `req.body.post`? GET requests don't typically have request bodies

Comment: hi @phil how is it going? so. I was trying to do a search using mern, you type something and find it in the backend and shows in the front , ok. and I don't know how to do it.  I try to do a form where I post, for  example: an user , and save it . Then in the other form I search this user or post for example. if it exists I fetch it and display in the front end , if not it shows not find . as I normal search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your intention is to search for posts and displaying results on front end.

**CLIENT_SIDE**

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect} from "react";

function Post() {

    const [post, setPost] = useState([])
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false)
    const [currentPost, setCurrentPost] = useState("")

useEffect (() => {
    const allPost = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get(`/post?post=${currentPost}`);
        if (res && Array.isArray(res.data) ) {
            setPost(res.data);
        } 
    }    
    allPost()
}, [currentPost])

return (

    <div>
        <form >
            <label></label>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search"
            onChange={(e)=> setCurrentPost(e.target.value)}/>

        </form>

        <button onClick={()=> setClick(true)}>search</button>
            {click && post.map((post) => (
                <h1>{post.post}</h1>
            ))}
    </div>
    )
}

export default Post;
```

**BACKEND**

```js
router.get("/" ,async (req,res ) => {
    const findPost = await Post.find({post: req.query.post});

    if(findPost&&findPost.length) {
        res.status(200).json(findPost);
    } else {
        res.status(200).json([]);// if not found,simply send empty array
    };

})
```

If you are not familiar with fundamentals of React or node. Please read their tutorial from their official website.